# How to using Jquery to call GWT binding event

Tags: jquery, gwt

I have a GWT demo project that includes a data table with 3 columns and 5 rows. i used gwt to implement:

```
table.addTableListener( new TableListener(){
            public void onCellClicked(SourcesTableEvents sender, int row, int cell) {
                demoFunc();
            }
        });
```

How can i create a html button and using jquery to call "onCellClicked" event.

```
<input type="button" id="button1" value="click here"/ >
```

..

```
$("#button1").click(function(){

//implement here to call "onCellClicked" event.

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at gquery, a jquery port of GWT: http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/
Haven't tested it beyond GWT 1.5.

Otherwise you'll need to do some JSNI, wrap a javascript function inside JSNI tags and call the javascript either using GWT or using jQuery or whichever way you want.

See the docs: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/2.2/FAQ_Client.html